# Erro na Função GetDay

Tags: javascript

Estou trabalhando em uma planilha com o Google Apps scripts para criar um fluxo de trabalho automático para Melhoria de Processos .

Estou diante de um problema que não posso resolver em uma linha do script (Linha folha 8 / e-mails). A função com problema é o `getDay ( )`, que gera um erro:

> The message says: TypeError : Can not find getDay function on the object. (line 8 , file " " )

Comment: Poste o que tem tentado.

Comment: experimente utilizar getDate(), getDay() retorna o número da semana (0-6).
Dá uma olhada aqui: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/date-field